# java.lang.SecurityException: sealing violation:

Tags: java, gwt

I am using GWT for my Java application. When I try to run it as web application, I get the following error:

> java.lang.SecurityException: sealing violation: can't seal package org.mortbay.util: already loaded

I can't find anything helpful if I Google for the error. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 8):

It means the package is sealed and you tried to load another jar also containing the package.

See [Sealing Packages within a JAR File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/sealman.html).

Comment: `org.mortbay.util` is a package of jetty, so you can look, if you have multiple jars of jetty in your classpath. As you are using GWT, I think it could include jetty by itself, so try removing all jetty jars from your classpath.

Answer (score 3):

Your current exception shows that you are using Jetty in your project. Possible problem might be that you have this jar available twice in your classpath.

Answer (score 1):

Goto your jar file,you will see .MF file.Open it.You will find Sealed:true.
Edit it, make it false.Over.

Comment: Better find the source of a duplicated jar. What will you do if one of your components gets updated? You will get a mess at the end.