# Jasper report giving java.lang.SecurityException:

Tags: java, oracle11g, jasper-reports, glassfish-3, oracle-apex

When i generate the jasper report and store in database that time giving me this error.

```
HTTP Status 500 -

    type Exception report

    message

    descriptionThe server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception
java.lang.SecurityException: sealing violation: can't seal package oracle.jdbc: already loaded

note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2.2 logs.
GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2.2
```

Glassfish Server logs
i don't know from which location i have to remove the jar files can you please suggest me location for glassfish v3. and also my CLASSPATH both users in Linux

```
[root@test1 ~]# cat .bash_profile
# .bash_profile
# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
        . ~/.bashrc
fi
# ROOT User specific environment and startup programs
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64/jdk1.7.0_71/bin
export PATH
[root@test1 ~]# su - oracle    
[oracle@test1 ~]$ cat .bash_profile
# .bash_profile
# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
        . ~/.bashrc
fi
# ORACLE User specific environment and startup programs
ORACLE_BASE=/u03/app1/oracle
ORACLE_HOME=/u03/app1/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1
ORACLE_SID=orcl
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib
PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH:$HOME/bin:/sbin:/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64/jdk1.7.0_71/bin
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.25.x86_64
export ORACLE_BASE ORACLE_HOME ORACLE_SID PATH LD_LIBRARY_PATH JAVA_HOME
[oracle@test1 ~]$


[#|2016-02-19T01:12:20.643-0500|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=92;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|2016-02-19 01:12:20,642 http-thread-pool-8080(11) ERROR [jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport] Fill 1: exception
    java.lang.SecurityException: sealing violation: can't seal package oracle.jdbc: already loaded
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.getAndVerifyPackage(URLClassLoader.java:395)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:417)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:412)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
            at org.apache.felix.framework.ExtensionManager$ExtensionManagerWiring.getClassByDelegation(ExtensionManager.java:871)
            at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.searchImports(BundleWiringImpl.java:1481)
            at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1427)
            at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:72)
            at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1843)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
            at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.loadBundleClass(Felix.java:1723)
            at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.loadClass(BundleImpl.java:926)
            at org.jvnet.hk2.osgiadapter.OSGiModuleImpl$4$1.run(OSGiModuleImpl.java:413)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at org.jvnet.hk2.osgiadapter.OSGiModuleImpl$4.loadClass(OSGiModuleImpl.java:409)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
            at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.APIClassLoaderServiceImpl$APIClassLoader.loadClass(APIClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:198)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:412)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:412)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
            at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1456)
            at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1359)
            at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:278)
            at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRClassLoader.loadClassForRealName(JRClassLoader.java:157)
            at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRClassLoader.loadClassForName(JRClassLoader.java:115)
            at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseField.getValueClass(JRBaseField.java:128)
            at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillField.getValueClass(JRFillField.java:96)
            at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRResultSetDataSource.getFieldValue(JRResultSetDataSource.java:131)
            at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.setOldValues(JRFillDataset.java:1317)
            at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.next(JRFillDataset.java:1218)
            at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.next(JRFillDataset.java:1194)
            at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.next(JRBaseFiller.java:1526)
            at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:142)
            at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:891)
            at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:804)
            at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.fillSubreport(JRFillSubreport.java:652)
            at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRSubreportRunnable.run(JRSubreportRunnable.java:59)
            at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRThreadSubreportRunner.run(JRThreadSubreportRunner.java:205)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: see this you have multiple jars with oracle driver. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10093176/java-lang-securityexception-sealing-violation

Comment: i don't know from which location i have to  remove the jar files can you please suggest me location for glassfish v3.