# java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError while running testng selenium testcase

Tags: java, selenium, exception, testng, galen

This is my testng class

```
/**
 * 
 */
package com.igate.test;


import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.igate.framework.BaseTestCase;
import com.igate.framework.ExecutionObject;
import com.igate.framework.GalenTestLayout;
import com.igate.framework.Reporter;
import com.igate.framework.WebDriver;

@Test
public class FleetBooking extends BaseTestCase {

    public FleetBooking() {
        super();
    }

    public ExecutionObject exeObj;

    @BeforeClass
    public void createDoc() throws Exception {
        Reporter.createDoc(deviceDetail);
        exeObj = new ExecutionObject();
    }

    public void test_case1() throws Exception {
        WebDriver oWD = null;

        if (runType.contains("mobile")) {
            oWD = new WebDriver(ObjMap, caps, deviceDetail);
        } else if (runType.contains("desktop")) {
            oWD = new WebDriver(ObjMap, caps);
        }

        try {

            oWD.startTestCase("test_casen1", exeObj);
            oWD.launchURL("https://fleet.igate.com/fleet/Login.htm");

            oWD.wait("MW");
            oWD.setPage("LoginPage");
            oWD.enterText("username", "831457");
            RemoteWebDriver driver = oWD.getDriver();
            System.out.println(" returned driver "+driver);
            GalenTestLayout layout = new GalenTestLayout();
            layout.testLayout(driver, "fleet");
            //oWD.layoutTest("fleet");
            /*try {
                System.out.println("layout under process");
                LayoutReport layoutReport = Galen.checkLayout(driver, "gspecs/fleet.gspec",
                        Arrays.asList("mobile","desktop"));
                // Creating a list of tests
                List<GalenTestInfo> tests = new LinkedList<GalenTestInfo>();

                // Creating an object that will contain the information about the
                // test
                GalenTestInfo test = GalenTestInfo
                        .fromString("Login page on mobile device test");

                // Adding layout report to the test report
                test.getReport().layout(layoutReport,
                        "check layout on mobile device");
                tests.add(test);



                System.out.println("report created in reports folder");
                // Exporting all test reports to html
                new HtmlReportBuilder().build(tests,
                        "reports");

            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("error 1"+e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }*/

            oWD.endTestCase();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("SYSOUT - exception : " + e);
            oWD.endTestCase();
        }

    }

}
```

Here is my **GalenTestLayout** class

```
package com.igate.framework;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.galenframework.api.Galen;
import com.galenframework.reports.GalenTestInfo;
import com.galenframework.reports.HtmlReportBuilder;
import com.galenframework.reports.model.LayoutReport;
import com.galenframework.testng.GalenTestNgTestBase;

public class GalenTestLayout {

    public RemoteWebDriver driver;

    @Test
    public void testLayout(RemoteWebDriver driver,String gspec) {

        System.out.println("driver in layout method "+driver);


        LayoutReport layoutReport;
        try {
            System.out.println("layout under process");
            layoutReport = Galen.checkLayout(driver, "gspecs/fleet.gspec",
                    Arrays.asList("mobile","desktop"));
            // Creating a list of tests
            List<GalenTestInfo> tests = new LinkedList<GalenTestInfo>();

            // Creating an object that will contain the information about the
            // test
            GalenTestInfo test = GalenTestInfo
                    .fromString("Login page on mobile device test");

            // Adding layout report to the test report
            test.getReport().layout(layoutReport,
                    "check layout on mobile device");
            tests.add(test);

            System.out.println("report created in reports folder");
            // Exporting all test reports to html
            new HtmlReportBuilder().build(tests,
                    "reports");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("error in layout method "+e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

I am getting error in My FleetBooking Class at

```
**GalenTestLayout layout = new GalenTestLayout();
            layout.testLayout(driver, "fleet");**
```

These are my error logs

```
[TestNG] Running:
  C:\Users\pmadge\AppData\Local\Temp\testng-eclipse-1054887367\testng-customsuite.xml

bin compiled version 1.1
2016-04-26 20:14:08 INFO  BaseTestCase:134 - Framework assigned in Internal Path : - Successfull
device size :3
*************taken device*********** 0
increasing count :1
 looped i :0
Starting ChromeDriver 2.20.353145 (343b531d31eeb933ec778dbcf7081628a1396067) on port 20891
Only local connections are allowed.
2016-04-26 20:14:10 INFO  WebDriver:739 - StartTestCase - test_casen1 - Successfull
2016-04-26 20:14:10 INFO  WebDriver:181 - Launch URL - : https://fleet.igate.com/fleet/Login.htm - Successfull
########$$$$$$$$$$%%%%%%%%%%%%%% ::::::::::::: null
2016-04-26 20:14:15 INFO  WebDriver:155 - SetPage - : LoginPage - Successfull
2016-04-26 20:14:17 INFO  WebDriver:610 - GetControl - Action Performed : username - Successfull
2016-04-26 20:14:17 INFO  WebDriver:622 - FetchControl - Action Performed - Successfull
2016-04-26 20:14:19 INFO  WebDriver:612 - GetControl - WebElement - Successfull
2016-04-26 20:14:19 INFO  WebDriver:206 - enterText - in: username value: 831457 - Successfull
 returned driver ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (92edabdf1bacb26c65c50ac893f7da3f)
driver in layout method ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (92edabdf1bacb26c65c50ac893f7da3f)
layout under process
FAILED: test_case1
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.galenframework.rainbow4j.Rainbow4J.loadImage(Rainbow4J.java:286)
    at com.galenframework.utils.GalenUtils.takeScreenshot(GalenUtils.java:314)
    at com.galenframework.browser.SeleniumBrowser.makeSimpleScreenshot(SeleniumBrowser.java:97)
    at com.galenframework.browser.SeleniumBrowser.createScreenshot(SeleniumBrowser.java:90)
    at com.galenframework.page.selenium.SeleniumPage.createScreenshot(SeleniumPage.java:161)
    at com.galenframework.api.Galen.checkLayoutForPage(Galen.java:100)
    at com.galenframework.api.Galen.checkLayout(Galen.java:86)
    at com.galenframework.api.Galen.checkLayout(Galen.java:69)
    at com.galenframework.api.Galen.checkLayout(Galen.java:59)
    at com.galenframework.api.Galen.checkLayout(Galen.java:154)
    at com.galenframework.api.Galen.checkLayout(Galen.java:128)
    at com.igate.framework.GalenTestLayout.testLayout(GalenTestLayout.java:31)
    at com.igate.test.FleetBooking.test_case1(FleetBooking.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: sealing violation: can't seal package com.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.jpeg2000: already loaded
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.getAndVerifyPackage(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.definePackageInternal(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(Unknown Source)
    at javax.imageio.spi.IIORegistry.registerApplicationClasspathSpis(Unknown Source)
    at javax.imageio.spi.IIORegistry.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at javax.imageio.spi.IIORegistry.getDefaultInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    ... 37 more


===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================

[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.jq.Main@1ed3c8d: 21 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.SuiteHTMLReporter@2efe5d: 76 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by [FailedReporter passed=0 failed=0 skipped=0]: 4 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.JUnitReportReporter@1f95c5d: 36 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.XMLReporter@a570f: 4 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.EmailableReporter2@81f4dc: 3 ms
```

My chrome driver is initialized properly as u can see in my output logs.

When I run the functionality **layout.testLayout(driver, "fleet");** as a independent class its running , but when I calling this method from testng class I am getting exception . I tried many alternatives but still it is giving me error

Answer (score 3):

The error is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: sealing violation: can't seal package com.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.jpeg2000: already loaded
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.getAndVerifyPackage(Unknown Source)
```

So that means you try to seal already loaded package. That package is in a file like jai_imageio-*.jar. Check if you have two similar jars and remove one of them.

Comment: you'r project is having some setup issues, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10093176/java-lang-securityexception-sealing-violation

Comment: Thanks alpert , without knowing my configuration you were able to know the root cause of the issue. Removing of that jar resolved my problem. Thanks alot !