# Cannot Initialize AppGameContainer Slick Java

Tags: java, slick2d

I cannot initialize the AppGameContainer class from the Slick2d library.

Here's my code:

**Main**

```
import org.BedrockGaming.game.TestGame;
import org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer;
import org.newdawn.slick.SlickException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    try {
        AppGameContainer agc = new AppGameContainer(new TestGame("Test"));
        agc.setDisplayMode(400, 400, false);
        agc.start();
    } catch (SlickException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
 }
}
```

**TestGame**

```
    package org.BedrockGaming.game;



import org.newdawn.slick.BasicGame;
import org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer;
import org.newdawn.slick.Graphics;
import org.newdawn.slick.SlickException;
public class TestGame  extends BasicGame{


    public TestGame(String title) {
        super(title);

}


@Override
public void render(GameContainer arg0, Graphics arg1) throws SlickException {
    
    
}

@Override
public void init(GameContainer arg0) throws SlickException {
    
    
}

@Override
public void update(GameContainer arg0, int arg1) throws SlickException {
    
    
}
}
```

**The Error**

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.createImplementation(Sys.java:129)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.<clinit>(Sys.java:116)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:135)
    at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer$1.run(AppGameContainer.java:39)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:312)
    at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.<clinit>(AppGameContainer.java:36)
    at Main.main(Main.java:9)
    Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: sealing violation: package org.lwjgl is sealed
    at 
 java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.getAndVerifyPackage(BuiltinClassLoader.java:869)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineOrCheckPackage(BuiltinClassLoader.java:840)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.defineOrCheckPackage(ClassLoaders.java:191)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:812)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:723)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:646)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:604)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:168)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at org.lwjgl.LWJGLUtil.loadIcon(LWJGLUtil.java:285)
    at org.lwjgl.LWJGLUtil.<clinit>(LWJGLUtil.java:259)
    ... 7 more
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java.lang.SecurityException: sealing violation:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10093176/java-lang-securityexception-sealing-violation)

Comment: Which package  should i unseal in that case? as said in the error , org.lwjgl is sealed but there is no "sealed" option in the manifest

Comment: I deleted the duplicate jar files  , but i am getting this error now;
``Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lwjgl64 in java.library.path``